# Basecamp: OAuth token could not be verified. The internal checksum failed, so the token data was somehow mangled or tampered with. (Python 3)

Tags: python, basecamp

I got the access token correctly but It always shows this message.

**Code**

```
ac_tk=requests.post(url).json()

project_id = #Project ID
url = f'http://3.basecampapi.com/{project_id}/projects.json'
headers1 = {'User-Agent': 'App_Name (example@domain.com)',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           'Authorization': f'Bearer {ac_tk}'
           }
response1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers1)

print("Text: ",response1.text,"\nStatus code: ",response1.status_code)
```

**Output**

```
Text:  {"error":"OAuth token could not be verified. The internal checksum failed, so the token data was somehow mangled or tampered with."} 
Status code:  401
```

**Acceess Token**

```
{'access_token': 'BAhbB0kiAbljAyMS0wNC0xMl.......',
 'expires_in': 12....0,
 'refresh_token': 'BAhbB0kiA......'}
```

Comment: Did you send the whole JSON as the token or just `BAhb...`?

Comment: @KlausD.
I got the entire token. I just deleted some part of it to hide.

Comment: That was not my question. Are you aware that the Token is just one of the values inside the JSON?

Comment: @KlausD. I sent the whole json.

Comment: @KlausD. I got the result when I sent the access token instead of the whole json. 
Thanks.